# Restful api how to pass info after basic http auth

Tags: java, rest, authentication, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am building a mobile app and Restful API, I want the user of the app to be able to do GET what ever resources he want without Authentication. But if he want to do POST he have to enter his username and pass.
I already made a HTTP basic Authentication by putting a filter in `web.xml`.

```
<filter>
<filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.service.RestAuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>AuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and there are the classes

```
public class AuthenticationService {
ClientsService s = new ClientsService();
public boolean authenticate(String authCredentials) {

    if (null == authCredentials)
        return false;
    // header value format will be "Basic encodedstring" for Basic
    // authentication. Example "Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4="
    final String encodedUserPassword = authCredentials.replaceFirst("Basic"
            + " ", "");
    String usernameAndPassword = null;
    try {
        byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decode(
                encodedUserPassword);
        usernameAndPassword = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(
            usernameAndPassword, ":");
    final String username = tokenizer.nextToken();
    final String password = tokenizer.nextToken();
    boolean authenticationStatus =s.auth(username, password);

    return authenticationStatus;
}
}
```

and the filter

```
public class RestAuthenticationFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {
public static final String AUTHENTICATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filter) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authCredentials = httpServletRequest
                .getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);

        // better injected
        AuthenticationService authenticationService = new AuthenticationService();

        boolean authenticationStatus = authenticationService
                .authenticate(authCredentials);

        if (authenticationStatus) {
            filter.doFilter(request, response);

        } else {
            if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpServletResponse
                        .setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
}
}
```

what i need to know is : how to pass the username and password or maybe just the id of the client to the methods of Restful after the Authentication.

Comment: After the authentication, from where do you access your REST service? If from there you have access to your session, you could try store you client's id in session after the successful authentication and afterwards retrieve it.

Comment: after the authentication it redirect me to the resource i asked for.  example ..../restful/offers   , i am not expert in restful but i think i should not store any think with the session right ?

Comment: is it acceptable to use a different path for POST requests? If so, you can map the `RestAuthenticationFilter` to this path only. I'm not sure if this proposal violates the REST principles.

Answer (score 0):

A solution different to my comment: you can look for the HTTP request method and then make a decision if you call a authentication method or not:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain filter) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        String authCredentials = httpServletRequest
                .getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER);

        boolean authenticationStatus;

        // check request method
        if (((HttpServletRequest).request).getMethod().equals("GET")) {
            authenticationStatus=true;
        } else {
            // better injected
            AuthenticationService authenticationService =
                  new AuthenticationService();
            authenticationStatus = authenticationService
                .authenticate(authCredentials);
        }

        if (authenticationStatus) {
            filter.doFilter(request, response);

        } else {
            if (response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
                HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                httpServletResponse
                        .setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

With JAX-RS a possible solution for obtaining more request information may look like this:

```
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@GET
@Path("offers")
@Produces("application/xml")
public YourList getOffers(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
{
    System.out.println("request to "+request.getRequestURI()+" , Auth: "+request.getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER));

// more stuff for obtaining data
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer it's very nice idea, but my question is after the authentication is done how to pass the username and password to the method GET or POST ?

Comment: you can pass a reference to the `HttpServletRequest` to your service methods, and then use `getHeader(AUTHENTICATION_HEADER)`

Comment: sometimes the solution just right there but you can't see it :).. thank you man that solve my problem.